# Audio Output Issue: Speakers Remain Silent When Headphones Are Connected

Tags: sound

Why is there a lack of audio output from the speakers on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 system, despite the headphones functioning properly? Additionally, could you kindly provide guidance on seamlessly transitioning between headphones and speakers?

Comment: Hi Sifat! To make sure that I understand you correctly please confirm: Your speakers and your headphones work. You just want to have sound output on the speakers WITH the headphones connected. Is that correct?

Also: How are you connecting your headphones? Via the normal barrel jack interface - so not bluetooth?

Comment: i am using dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04, in my windows it's work fine.
yes both of my speaker and headphone connected and i am using barrel jack.